# Getting error in displaying text through textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have created an application in which i have added a text through UITextView programmatically and add this textview as a subview of custom ViewController. Problem is that the text is not displaying in this ViewController. Please help me through this.

Code for this--

```
UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.text = @"text here";
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:90]];
textView.delegate = self;
[textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[textView setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
textView.frame=CGRectMake(150,300,self.view.frame.size.width-40,200);
//textView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
[textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: You asked a similar question yesterday. Is this different or the same? Also what do you mean "text is not displaying". Make sure you write a question in a way that it is absolutely clear.

Comment: your textView showing on viewcontroller may be you can not seeing because of your viewController color is white and also textView background color is white. Change your textView background color and set fontsize 20 for example.

[textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];

Comment: Is it the text which is not displaying, or the textView itself? Setting a yellow background color on the textView would be a good way to check this.

Comment: Check please, does your self.view has a non-zero frame?

Comment: Your TextView text is displaying but you have given TextView background color **Clear Color** and textcolor to **white Color**.so you can not see textview text give some different color and check.

Comment: No , its totally different from yesterday question. Actually i want to ask that how add the text through text in custom view controller.for example we have a inbuilt viewcontroller in xcode and suppose i added a new file, name TextViewController now i want to add textView as a subview of this view controller(TextViewController) . And problem is that text is unable to show on this viewcontroller

Comment: and getting the error also like this : Unknown class _TtC18TextViewController18TextViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: I have checked it but it's not displaying @BrettDonald

Answer (score 0):

You are using the textcolor of textview as White color, and background of that textview to clearcolor. Make sure your viewcontrollers view's background should be of dark color or you have to change the text color of textview to some dark color like blackcolor.

Comment: i have change the textcolor and text background colour but i didn't get any result and getting the error : Unknown class _TtC18TextViewController18TextViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: So check that your View Controller in Interface Builder is linked to the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IBuilder missed customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target"

To fix it, open storyboard as source code and replace this line:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass"
sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

to this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass"
 customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Comment: after replacing this , it is showing the error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x17d7ae50>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'TextViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x243e0137 0x3267bc77 0x27f673c9 0x6c0d9 0x27a4ba7b 0x27a4ba21 0x27a365c5 0x27a4b461 0x27a4b133 0x27a44a41 0x27a1ac05 0x27c9131f 0x27a19607 0x243a622f 0x243a5643 0x243a3cc1 0x242ef9a1 0x242ef7b3 0x2ba701a9 0x27a7a695 0x6c449 0x32c23aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: are you displaying large data in textview

Comment: and one more thing clean and then build again